# Sound Triggered by Rigid Body Collisions?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, audio

I have been working in blender on a simple rigid body simulation. I've done a few before, so I have a pretty decent idea about how it works. But, I realized, it would add a whole new degree of awesomeness to the final animation if I could have a short sound recording be played when the objects collide.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: You can add a [speaker](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/audio/speaker.html) and give it a rigid body constraint, not sure if you can use that to control it's sound.